# How to create list of list (list<classname>) in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am new in java ,now i need a help.I recently work in Spring Boot framework,
anyone help me for create and manipulate a list as shown here.

[image: array list concept]

Comment: `List<List<YourClass>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: I think there is no any relation between your question and Spring Boot.

Comment: So you want a List<List<Integer>>, is that right? If you're not familiar with collections, then learn collections first. Google for "Java collections tutorial" and "Java generics tutorial". That has nothing to do with Spring Boot, but you should definitely learn the basics with simpler stuff than Spring Boot first.

Comment: There are many tutorials you can find in internet to learn Java.

https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist/

For now you can declare list of list like

List<List<Integer>> listOfIntegerLists = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 3):

What you show in the image could be implemented by a `List` of `List` or a `Map`.

If the left number in the image starts at `0` and are consecutive numbers, declaring `List<List<Integer>>` is a correct approach.

You can populate it in this way :

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>();
listOfList.add(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3)); 
listOfList.add(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));
```

And retrieve the values according to the requested index :

```
List<Integer> secondList = listOfList.get(1);
```

---

If the left number in the image doesn't start at `0` or are not consecutive numbers, declaring `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` is a better approach.

For each integer key, you have a `List` of integer.

If the map should be sorted according to the insertion order, use a `LinkedHashMap` :

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

If the map should be ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, use a `TreeMap` :

```
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Of course you could implement it with a `List` of `List` such as 
`List<List<Integer>>` but it would be less meaningful and more cumbersome.

Comment: `List<Integer, List<Integer>>`????

Comment: @Andreas Oh my gosh... Thanks

Comment: Why would `Map` be better than `List` for storing the data in the picture, where the numbers are consecutive, starting from `0`? `List` is perfectly fine for that. Why would it be more cumbersome? --- If the outer dimension is sparse, sure, but if you make that assumption, why not for the inner dimension? Please be consistent with your assumptions.

Comment: @Andreas  In the actual example, if we consider that the first number is an index similar to an array index, yes, it is true. I answered by assuming that it may be not always the case. I updated my answer to reflect two possibilities. Thank you.

Comment: If the inner lists can be fixed-size lists, created using `Arrays.asList`, why not do the same for the outer list? `List<List<Integer>> listOfList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3), Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));` --- Of course, fixed-size lists may or may not be good, depending on what question means by *"help me for create and **manipulate** a list"*.

Comment: It is valid. But I find this nested level a little bit less readable. About `Arrays.asList()` limitations, the question indeed doesn't contain any enough information to know whether it is or not the correct way. As as you guess, I use it here  as it is a clear and shorter way to populate List with multiple elements.  If this doesn't match with the OP requirements, OP could still look for on SO why `UnsupportedOperationException` may be risen as one uses `Arrays.asList()`

Answer (score 0):

**I believe you can use list within a list concept. Here each element of the list is itself a list.**

```
List<List<ClassYouWant>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inserting data into this list:

```
List<List<ClassYouWant>> outerList= new ArrayList<>();

List<ClassYouWant> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
outerList.add(innerList );
```

Also you can achieve the same with other Collection data structures i.e Set within a Set or Map within a Map.

Additionally if you have a scenario where each list can represented by a unique value you can use List within Map

```
Map<AnyClass , List<ClassYouWant>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

AnyClass - Can be any unique value which represents your class